# CKEditor : Remove default text "image preview" in box using CKEditor

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

firstly thanks in advance.
in CKEditor when i click on image tab in tool box , the image properties window open, in this window , we upload the image and also image preview box is there , but when the "image properties " windows open in the "image preview" box there is some text like show in this link 
http://ckeditor.com/demo but i want to remove the default text in "image preview" box at initialize time. how can we done ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the preview text by setting `image_previewText`

See that URL: http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.image_previewText

Answer (score 6):

You need to add this to your config:

`config.image_previewText = ' ';`

I found you have to set it to an empty space rather than an empty string else it defaults to lorem ipsum.